# HashSet::add usage doesn't lead to "non-static method cannot be referenced from static context"

Tags: java

```
Set<Long> testSet = new Random().longs(100, 1000000000L, 999999999999L).collect(HashSet::new, HashSet::add, HashSet::addAll);
```

This code works fine, but I expect it to say, that I reference non-static method with static Context. Moreover, HashSet.add method does suit signature of ObjLongConsumer.

collect definition:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> var1, ObjLongConsumer<R> var2, BiConsumer<R, R> var3);
```

ObjLongConsumer:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ObjLongConsumer<T> {
    void accept(T var1, long var2);
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashSet::add` is a method reference, and can be used in any context. Since you refer to a non-static method, it must be called with the object, which will be `this` (the context, `var1` in the `ObjLongConsumer`).

Answer (score 0):

The code can be replaced to this:

```
Set<Long> testSet = new Random().longs(100, 1000000000L, 999999999999L)
                .collect(new Supplier<Set<Long>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Set<Long> get() {
                        return new HashSet<>();
                    }
                }, new ObjLongConsumer<Set<Long>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Set<Long> longs, long value) {
                        longs.add(value);
                    }
                }, new BiConsumer<Set<Long>, Set<Long>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Set<Long> longs, Set<Long> longs2) {
                        longs.addAll(longs2);
                    }
                });
```

And you see what's going on "under the hood". Method references is just a syntactic sugar.